# Carry/Borrow in VHDL ALU

Tags: vhdl, addition, alu

I am making a generic N-bit ALU in VHDL.  I am having trouble assigning the value for the carry for addition, or borrow for subtraction.  I have tried the following:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL; 

entity alu is
    generic(n: integer :=1); --Default to 1
    port (
        a : in std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
        b : in std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
        op : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        output : out std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
        carryborrow: out std_logic 
    );
end alu;

architecture Behavioral of alu is
    signal result: std_logic_vector(n downto 0); 
begin
process( a, b, op )
begin
    case op is
    when "00" => 
        result(n) <= '0'; 
        result(n-1 downto 0) <= a and b; --and gate 
        output <= result(n-1 downto 0); 
        carryborrow <= '0'; 
    when "01" => 
        result(n) <= '0'; 
        result(n-1 downto 0) <= a or b; --or gate 
        output <= result(n-1 downto 0); 
        carryborrow <= '0'; 
    when "10" => 
        result(n) <= '0'; 
        result(n-1 downto 0) <= std_logic_vector(signed(a) + signed(b)); --addition
        output <= result(n-1 downto 0); 
        carryborrow <= result(n); 
    when "11" => 
        result(n) <= '0';
        result(n-1 downto 0) <= std_logic_vector(signed(a) - signed(b)); --subtraction
        output <= result(n-1 downto 0); 
        carryborrow <= result(n); 
    when others => 
        NULL; 
    end case; 

end process;

end Behavioral;
```

This seems to set the `carryborrow` bit to always be 0.  How can I assign it to what it should be without type errors?

Comment: Consider reading [The CARRY flag and OVERFLOW flag in binary arithmetic](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt) all the way through. Binary signed numbers (2'sC) are susceptible to overflow from carrying through the sign bit. Do you mean to do unsigned arithmetic?

Comment: @user1155120 So then I shouldn't be converting my vectors to `signed`, right?

Comment: I'm missing your test bench. Testing your code is usually the way to go: it shows you what went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are bugs in your code:

i) You have not taken into account the fact that signals are not updated immediately. Consequently, the following lines will not do as I think you are expecting:

```
    result(n) <= '0'; 
    result(n-1 downto 0) <= a and b; --and gate 
    output <= result(n-1 downto 0);
```

Instead, you need to take the lines driving `output` and `carryborrow` outside the combinational process, as you can see below.
ii) Assuming you wish this code to be synthesisable, simply putting `NULL` in your always branch will result in latches being inferred. You need to drive `result` in the others branch, too.

So, making an assumption about how your carry output is to behave with the `and` and `or` operations, this is how I would have written your code:

```
architecture Behavioral of alu is
    signal result: std_logic_vector(n downto 0); 
begin
process( a, b, op )
begin
    case op is
    when "00" => 
        result <= '0' & (a and b); --and gate 
    when "01" => 
        result <= '0' & (a or b); --or gate 
    when "10" => 
        result <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(a), n+1) + resize(signed(b), n+1)); --addition
    when "11" => 
        result <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(a), n+1) - resize(signed(b), n+1)); --subtraction
    when others => 
        result <= (others => 'X');
    end case; 
  end process;

  output <= result(n-1 downto 0); 
  carryborrow <= result(n); 

end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 1):

I normally do this:

```
result <= std_logic_vector(signed(a(n-1) & a) + signed(b(n-1) & b));
result <= std_logic_vector(signed(a(n-1) & a) - signed(b(n-1) & b));
```

Sign extend and then do the operation to take care of overflow, when the result is one extra bit long.

Comment: This results in an error:  `Error, type error in expression`

Comment: @SaraTibbetts Or you could use the `resize` function in `numeric_std` which does the same thing for `signed` types, but also correctly extends `unsigned` types too. ie `result <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(a), n+1) + resize(signed(b), n+1))`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, consider this in a 4 bit environment, say `a="0101"` and `b="1001"`. Adding them shall give the `output="1110"`, with NO carry.

However, sign extending with `resize(signed(a), n+1)` and `resize(signed(b), n+1)` will set `a="00101"` and `b="11001"` and hence `result="11110"` and `carryborrow='1'`, which is wrong!

By sign extending vectors `a` and `b`, the numeral range has increased to 5 bits, and thus `result` needs to be 6 bits to be able to hold carry, and we're back to square one.
Vectors `a` and `b` should only be zero extended, that is `'0' & a` and `'0' & b` before adding them to `result`, and then `carryborrow`, as MSB(Most Significant Bit) of `result`, will get the correct value.

Comment: Hello RackHam and welcome to SO. I can't really verify your answer but I can ask you to try to tidy it up. It would benifit from some formatting - making it easier to read!